# Fortran run-time error when using statsmodels in Python

Tags: python, fortran, runtime-error, statsmodels, pyscripter

I am attempting to generate a fairly simple ARMA model using STATSMODELS in Python (Pyscripter IDE). I kept getting an odd error, so I took a step back and tried the following example. I get the same error.

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma.html

Any information would be helpful. Full disclosure, I'm a scientist but not a COMPUTER scientist.

I get the following error when running the script:

```
Intel(r) Visual Fortran run-time error

forrtl: severe (9): permission to access file denied, unit 8, file C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScipter\iterate.dat

Image              PC          Routine    Line       Source
libifcoremd.dll    07DA1A70    Unknown    Unknown    Unknown

...
_lbfgsb.ypd        08344077    Unknown    Unknown    Unknown
...
```

Answer (score 1):

my guess

`iterate.dat` is the logfile for the optimization that scipy fmin_lbfgsb writes. And the fortran extension that implements lbfgsb doesn't have permission to write to `C:\Program Files`

possible solutions, I'm not sure which will work:

- run the script in a local working directory where you have write access.
- suppress the logfile, `iprint=0` as `fit` option might work http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html (maybe `disp=0`  works also)
- use a different optimizer that doesn't print from Fortran (only as last resort, e.g. with `bfgs` )

Comment: iprint=0 as fit option works, but only for 1 run. If I try to run the exact same code again I get the same error. I don't know much about the behind the scenes workings of it all, but is this likely an issue with my computer or the scipy optimization code?

Thanks for the help. At least now I can limp forward.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today and the issue was solved by doing two different things I found on StackOverflow.

```
model.fit(iprint=0, disp=0)
```

Use the following two parameters:

1. iprint=0
2. disp=0